# How can I fill the rest of the space (NumberLoops)

Tags: java

This is my Solution

[image]

Result of the Sol is

[image]

But I need this result. I want to know how to fill the space with **"."**. 
I would appreciate your advice.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run another `for` loop. See this code:

```
public void run() {
    for (int i=0; i<5 ; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<5-i-1 ; j++) {
            System.out.print(".");
        }

        System.out.print(i+1);
        //Run another loop
        for (int k=0; k<i ; k++) {
            System.out.print(".");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: wow.. thank you!  I didn't try to use another loop for that ^^; I was an idiot

Answer (score 0):

Stick with two `for` loops, but reverse the direction of the inner loop and print a `.` unless the inner value equals the outer value, in which case you print that.

```
for(int i=1; i<=5; i++)
{
  for(int j=5; j>=1; j--)
    System.out.print(i==j ? i : ".");
  System.out.println();
}
```

Output:

```
....1
...2.
..3..
.4...
5....
```